# Algolia Places error 'container' must point to an <input> element

Tags: javascript, algolia

I've been trying to implement Algolia Places into my signup page and struggling to get it to apply to the city input.

**Console Error:**
Uncaught Error: Algolia Places: 'container' must point to an  element.

I've tried various selectors without success:

- container: "#id-city"
- container: document.querySelector('#id_city')
- container: document.querySelector('input#id_city')
- container: document.querySelector("input[id='id_city']")
- container: document.querySelector("input[name='city']")

I'm sure it's something silly but don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks for your help!

```
<input type="text" class="form-control " name="city" id="id_city" value="" size="20" maxlength="120">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/places.js@1.4.15"></script>
<script>

var options = {
  container: "#id-city",
  type: "city",
};
places(options);
</script>
```

Comment: oliver checkout the answer if that suffices your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the following is fine. Run the snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var placesAutocomplete = places({
        container: document.getElementById('id_city')
      });
    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/places.js@1.4.15"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="city" id="id_city" value="" size="20" maxlength="120" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var placesAutocomplete = places({
    container: document.getElementById('id_city')
  });
</script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I had tried that script but my mistake was to put all the code in the header rather than prior to the body being closed.